# Show Kafka topic title as a field in Kibana, logstash add_field?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash, kibana

I have logstash with ElasticSearch & Kibana 7.6.2
I connect logstash to Kafka as follows:

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "******"
    topics_pattern => [".*"]
    decorate_events => true
    add_field => { "[topic_name]" => "%{[@metadata][kafka][topic]}"}
  }
}
filter {
  date {
    match => [ "timestamp", "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "logstash"
    document_type => "logs"
  }
}
```

It's OK and work. But I field `topic_name` show as `%{[@metadata][kafka][topic]}`

[image: kibana-capture-1]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe the timing of the add_field-operator is not correct. I would suggest that you implement the mutate filter **after** the kafka input in a dedicated filter. Let me know if that worked.

Comment: @apt-get_install_skill Could u please give me a sample?

Comment: `input {
kafka {
bootstrap_servers => "******"
topics_pattern => [".*"]
decorate_events => true
}
}
filter {
mutate{
add_field => { "[topic_name]" => "%{[@metadata][kafka][topic]}"}
}

date {
match => [ "timestamp", "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
}
}
output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
index => "logstash"
document_type => "logs"
}
}`

Comment: Notice that the add_field operation is now after the input plugin. Give it a try.

Comment: @apt-get_install_skill Thanks, it resolve the problem, please post an answer to check it as answer.

Comment: I did. Glad I could help you and appreciating that you want to accept my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of the sprintf format you are using ( `%{[@metadata][kafka][topic]}` ) to get the value of that field is correct.

Allegedly there is no such field `@metadata.kafka.topic` in your document. Therefore the sprintf can't obtain the field value and as a result, the newly created field contains the sprintf call as a string.

However, since you set `decorate_events => true`, the metadata fields should be available as stated in the documentation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html):

> Metadata is only added to the event if the decorate_events option is set to true (it defaults to false).

I can imagine that the `add_field` action set in the **input plugin** causes the issue. Since the `decorate_events` option first enables the addition of the metadata fields, the `add_field` action should come at second place **after the input plugin.**

Your configuration would then look like this:

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "******"
    topics_pattern => [".*"]
    decorate_events => true
  }
}

filter {
  mutate{
    add_field => { "[topic_name]" => "%{[@metadata][kafka][topic]}"}
  }

  date {
    match => [ "timestamp", "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "logstash"
    document_type => "logs"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
add_field => { "topic_name" => "%{[@metadata][kafka][topic]}"}
```

i.e. `[topic_name]` -> `topic_name`

Comment: Thats not the issue. The syntax is correct as you should see by the screenshot the OP posted (the field gets added but the value can not be obtained by sprintf)

Comment: @jzzfs I did it. No change